# Whats the difference between using serialize and store methods

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I couldn't find much information online but it seems either methods used in the model enable the same functionality. How are they different and when should one be used over the other?

Example code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :extra_stuff
  serialize :extra_stuff_too
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the [`store` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)? How about the [`serialize` docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store wraps serialize so that you can store a hash in a column on your record. You can't however query data in a store.

Serialize basically saves the data as YAML in the record.

Serialize can store an array of things:

```
[thing1, thing2, thing3]
```

Store deals in hashes of key value pairs:

```
{thing1: "thing1 value", thing2: "thing2 value"}
```